# VSCode - editor.codeActionsOnSave - source.fixAll.eslint - true for errors, false for warnings

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I want VS Code to fix all linting errors on save, but ignore warnings.

This rule fixes everything it can on save:

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
    rules: {
        'react/self-closing-comp':
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
                ? 'error'
                : 'warn',
```

But I want it ignore warnings.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/208? Also: why do you have *conditional* linting rules? Do you expect your code to be reformatted for different environments?

Comment: Thanks yes I've seen it, it's about `autoFixOnSave` which is now deprecated. Conditional linting rules are there because I sometimes I want different rules in different environments. It's not linked to the fact that I want errors auto-formatted and warnings not.